# Unattended imaging failing with IE 11

Tags: windows, image, internet-explorer, image-processing, usb-drive

Unable to get past this error msg when deploying windows 7 with ie11 from usb drive.  Works just fine if i remove IE 11. but I need IE  11 in my new image.  How to I quickly resolve this error
[image]

Here is my specialize unattended portion.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

issue was with xml setup file.  IE 11 needs all headers in to install correctly.